# Cannot make GET request to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a get endpoint in my node.js app that I can call locally, but when I call it after hosting the application on Heroku, I receive an HTML response instead of the desired JSON.

This is my node.js API Endpoint
`app.get("api/confirmation/:email/:token", confirmEmail);`

From my attempts to test, I am sure the server is receiving my query, but I am receiving HTML in response.

[image]